# Does [commercial] and [monetization] tags have too big of an overlap for them to be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Background: I have asked [How can free and open source projects be monetized? (2015)](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/88/61) back when we had no idea what to do with our tags, and [monetization] was created since that felt like the tag that had its purpose and would exist on Stack Overflow as well if it also accepted general-purpose questions like these.

Now, though, another tag [commercial](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial) is up:

> Commercial activity is anything to make money. This tag is for questions about making money with Open Source / Free Software, ... (disamb)

This feels like it is basically trying to be a more specific scope than [monetization](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monetization), which sits as currently:

> For questions about generating revenue from an open project

As written, they seem like they are the same tag. However, there is likely some nuance between "making money as a non-terminal goal" and "seeking commercial activities that fits a project", which I think if we are able to describe and refine their descriptions to match that nuance then it would make both tags better, and if we can't then it may make searching more difficult with the tags split as is.

What do you think?